# How to get the last record from Ms Access table

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, max

I have 2 tables named *Reefers* and *Alerts*. I want to join these two tables.

Now, how to get a result that shows the last record of each *ReeferNo* from *Alerts* table where the *AlertType* is equal to *"Temperatures"*?

```
TABLE 1: Reefers                            
ReeferNo    Transporter                     
E-110       Express1                        
E-111       Express1                        
E-112       Express1                        
A-001       A-Trucking                      
A-002       A-Trucking                      

TABLE 2: Alerts                         
AlertDateTime   ReceivedDateTime    AlertType   ReeferNo    Temperature Location        
5/2/15 9:53 AM  5/2/15 9:58 AM     Arrival       E-110        5.2      Warehouse        
5/2/15 9:48 AM  5/2/15 9:53 AM     Departure     E-111        5.4      Warehouse        
5/2/15 9:40 AM  5/2/15 9:45 AM     Temperatures  A-001        11.37    Warehouse        
5/2/15 9:38 AM  5/2/15 9:43 AM     Temperatures  A-001        10.06    Store        
5/2/15 9:35 AM  5/2/15 9:40 AM     Temperatures  A-001        10.02    Store        
5/2/15 9:19 AM  5/2/15 9:24 AM     Departure     A-001        10.02    Store        
5/2/15 9:12 AM  5/2/15 9:17 AM     Temperatures  A-002        10.37    Warehouse        
5/2/15 9:06 AM  5/2/15 9:11 AM     Temperatures  A-002        12.62    Warehouse        
5/2/15 9:04 AM  5/2/15 9:09 AM     Arrival       A-002        12.62    Warehouse
```

RESULT MUST BE:

```
ReeferNo  Transporter   AlertDateTime   ReceivedDateTime    AlertType   Temperature Location
E-110     Express1
E-111     Express1
E-112     Express1
A-001     A-Trucking   5/2/15 9:40 AM   5/2/15 9:45 AM    Temperatures     11.37       Warehouse
A-002     A-Trucking   5/2/15 9:12 AM   5/2/15 9:17 AM    Temperatures     10.37       Warehouse
```

I'm using below code but it's not giving me result that I want.

```
SELECT Reefers.ReeferNo, Reefers.Transporter, Alerts.AlertType,     
Alerts.AlertDateTime, Alerts.Temperature, Alerts.Location, 
Alerts.ReceivedDateTime
FROM Reefers INNER JOIN (Alerts INNER JOIN (SELECT 
Alerts.ReeferNo, 
MAX(Alerts.ReceivedDateTime) 
AS MaxReceivedDateTime 
FROM Alerts 
GROUP BY Alerts.ReeferNo)  AS temptable ON (Alerts.ReeferNo =     
temptable.ReeferNo) AND (Alerts.ReceivedDateTime = 
temptable.MaxReceivedDateTime)) ON Reefers.ReeferNo = Alerts.ReeferNo
WHERE (((Alerts.AlertType)="Temperatures"));
```

UPDATE:

I changed the required result. Instead of word Null, leave it blank for the *Reefers* without temperatures *AlertType*.

Comment: How do you narrow down the `E-110 / E-111` ? Like, what if there's 10 different records, but none of them have `Temperatures`.. Are there 10 NULL records?

Comment: E-110 and E-110 are the Reefer numbers (ID). These two Reefers has no alert of temperatures that's why it showing in result as Null or lets say blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with a query which pulls everything you want for those *Reefers* which had at least one temperature alert:

```sql
SELECT
    sub1.ReeferNo,
    a2.AlertDateTime,
    a2.ReceivedDateTime,
    a2.AlertType,
    a2.Temperature,
    a2.Location
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            a1.ReeferNo,
            Max(a1.AlertDateTime) AS MaxOfAlertDateTime
        FROM Alerts AS a1
        WHERE a1.AlertType='Temperatures'
        GROUP BY a1.ReeferNo
    ) AS sub1
    INNER JOIN Alerts AS a2
    ON
            (sub1.MaxOfAlertDateTime = a2.AlertDateTime)
        AND (sub1.ReeferNo = a2.ReeferNo);
```

Then `LEFT JOIN` the *Reefers* table to a subquery based on that first query ...

```sql
SELECT
    r.ReeferNo,
    r.Transporter,
    sub2.AlertDateTime,
    sub2.ReceivedDateTime,
    sub2.AlertType,
    sub2.Temperature,
    sub2.Location
FROM
    Reefers AS r
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            sub1.ReeferNo,
            a2.AlertDateTime,
            a2.ReceivedDateTime,
            a2.AlertType,
            a2.Temperature,
            a2.Location
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    a1.ReeferNo,
                    Max(a1.AlertDateTime) AS MaxOfAlertDateTime
                FROM Alerts AS a1
                WHERE a1.AlertType='Temperatures'
                GROUP BY a1.ReeferNo
            ) AS sub1
            INNER JOIN Alerts AS a2
            ON
                    (sub1.MaxOfAlertDateTime = a2.AlertDateTime)
                AND (sub1.ReeferNo = a2.ReeferNo)
        ) AS sub2
    ON r.ReeferNo = sub2.ReeferNo;
```